# FileProvider "fails to find configured root" exception. in some devices only

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

- In my android app i am getting all images of device and setting it in `RecyclerView`by casting files to uri using below code.

> ```
> if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 21) { 
>             uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName()+".fileprovider", file);
>         } else {
>             uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
>         }
> ```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>

    <files-path name="files" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
    <cache-path name="cached_files" path="." />
    <external-cache-path name="cached_files" path="." />


</paths>
```

provider in AndroidManifest.xml

```
...

 <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="<my.package.name>.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
  </provider>

...
```

here the problem is with devices with api level 21 and above. it gives me below exception.

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/sdcard1/DCIM/20170914_143147.jpg
                                                                           at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:711)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
                                                                           at com.abc.adapters.GalleryAdapterCollage.getView(GalleryAdapterCollage.java:91)
                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2360)
                                                                           at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1060)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17573)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17573)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5561)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1083)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17573)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17573)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5561)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17573)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5561)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17573)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5561)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17573)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5561)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17573)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5561)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2696)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17573)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2161)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1520)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1163)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6190)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:773)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:586)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:556)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:759)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:975)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

-

- In some devices  with **api level 21 and above**, its working fine. But i am getting this exception in some devices like **oppo, mi** etc.
- from path in exception i tried using  `<external-path name="external_files" path="DCIM/" />` but that is not working too.
- I am using glide to load images from uri.
- I tried many similar questions link here but haven't got solution.

**Questions**

- How to fix this exception in these devices?
- Is there any other way through which I can load those images smoothly like happening in glide?

Comment: Please post readable code. How should we know what `allImages.get(position)` contains?

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to change that..now edited..it is an instance of file.

Comment: So you think that we instead know what file contains or which path that is? We already knew that it would be a File instance as we know that function. Not very informative.

Comment: It contains /storage/sdcard1/DCIM/20170914_143147.jpg this path. which is there in exception.

Comment: Can you tell something more? How did you obtain that path? Is it a special path? Is there a /storage/sdcard0 too? What does getExternalStorageDirectory() deliver?